# Example of a finite dimensional algebra over $C$ with a simple module of dimension $2013$

Tags: algebras

What is an example of a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with a simple module of dimension $2013$?

I don't know if the general case holds here (there exists $A$ and a simple module of dimension $n$) or if there is a specific example for $2013$.

My first idea was a group algebra, something like $\mathbb{C}C_{2013k}$, but this is a commutative algebra so all simple modules will be one-dimensional.

Comment: Try showing that the height n column vectors are a simple module for the nxn matrix algebra.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You can make it a group algebra: $S_n$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: Am I right in the thinking that the span of $\{(1,0,\ldots,0 ,-1),(0,1,\ldots ,0,-1),\ldots ,(0,0,\ldots,1,-1)\}\subset\mathbb{C}^{2014}$ is a simple module?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, you are right, it is a simple $S_{2013}$ module.

Comment: How do I prove that it is a simple module?

Comment: @Andrew: Simple means : "the transforms of every non-zero vector in the module span the whole module". The module consists of all the $n$-dimensional vector with the sum of components $0$. Take one such vector $v \ne 0$. Then not all of its components are equal. Say $v_i \ne v_j$. Try to find combination of $v$ and a two component flip of $v$ that span $e_i - e_j$, then you are almost done.